# Как реализовать активити с фрагментами внутри

Tags: android

Как реализовать такую штуку. Хотелось бы чтобы при открытии SecondActivity открывалась активити как на картинке. Активити содержит фрагменты, которые можно переключать кнопками вправо или влево, в каждом фрагменте будет по 5 элементов, которые можно листать вправо или влево свайпом.

В какую сторону копать? Как лучше реализовать?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Оно? https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/recyclerview

Comment: ViewPager является контейнером для фрагментов. Можете создать новый проект и выбрать TabbedActivity, чтобы посмотреть как это работает

Comment: Спасибо, попробую.

Answer (score 1):

Создайте в активити ViewPager

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">
    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Вам так же понадобится создать отдельный фрагмент для ViewPager (Класс + лейаут).

```
private ViewPager pager;
private PagerAdapter pagerAdapter;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    pagerAdapter = new MyFragmentPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    pager.setAdapter(pagerAdapter);

    pager.setOnPageChangeListener(new OnPageChangeListener() {

      @Override
      public void onPageSelected(int position) {
      }

      @Override
      public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset,
          int positionOffsetPixels) {
      }

      @Override
      public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
      }
    });
  }
```

И класс наследующий от PagerAdapter

```
class MyFragmentPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public MyFragmentPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
      super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
      return PageFragment.newInstance(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
      return PAGE_COUNT;
    }

  }
```

Здесь можете посмотреть более детальное руководство
https://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/228-urok-125-viewpager.html